# Prevent css and js inheritence in ascx

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, ascx

I have an application with only one aspx page (Default.aspx).
This page loads .ascx controls as needed.
All these controls are using the same JS and CSS file.
Now I want to apply Bootstrap on some of them.  But I am scared that bootstrap will break some CSS and JS.
So I am thinking about wrapping each control in an Iframe (because what I know is: 
Iframe blocks inheritance of CSS and JS).
Is my solution ok ?
Or Is there a way to know which CSS and JS is needed by each control?

thanks

Comment: bootstrap should be used at the start of your project ,if you add bootstrap right now you will need to manually fix any problems that will arise

Comment: the iframe idea is very bad in my opinion

Comment: @madalinivascu why do you think is bad ?
what is wrong with iframe ?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is that even if you're breaking your application markup into controls (ascx files), you should apply a consistent theme and serve just one bundle of CSS and one bundle of JS. This will help performance of your site as well as be easier to maintain.  Also, it'll be easier to keep a consistent look and feel for your users.

So if you're going to use Bootstrap, use it everywhere.  Write your JS functions such that they aren't dependent on a given markup, and so on.